# Which enolate of butanone is more stable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, stability

Consider butanone (**A**) and its two possible enolates **B** & **C**.

Which of the two enolates will be more stable? **B** because of the more stable primary carbanion, or **C** because of more stable enolate (better hyperconjugation)?

[image]

Comment: Very much related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17103

Comment: This is a classic example of forming enolates under thermodynamic or kinetic control.

Comment: in my opinion it should be C.